# integrate webcam on windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, webcam, windows-phone-8-emulator

Can I integrate my pc webcam on wp8emulator?

I am developing an app that use de phone camera and i don't have the real device to try on .

```
void cam_Initialized(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Succeeded)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {


                    //Camera a fost initializata
});
```

I hope to can find some code .

Answer (score 2):

That will not work. The emulator's camera will only ever output a black screen. You need a real device to test camera based apps correctly. Sadly, there isn't a method to work around this to my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

what about this info from MSDN?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207050(v=vs.105).aspx

Seems like its possible and allowed. There's also some reading about capturing video.

Comment: Please don't just post links as answers. Stackoverflow should be the end of the search for an answer not an intermediate step to it. Extract the most significant points of the MSDN article and keep the link to it as a reference to get more information.

Comment: You should provide more detail instead of only giving reference links. It should b a comment. If you don't have privileges then you should provide enough detail to support your answer. Or provide to the point answer. Stack Overflow won't allow only references as answers.